# How to put brackets in a list accordingly in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to put brackets in a list. This is the code:

```
list_1 = [1,2,2]
list_2 = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

I want to use the numbers in 'list_1' to put brackets on 'list_2'. Like this:

```
[[1],[2,3],[4,5]]
```

How can i achieve this using Python 3?

Comment: With what "grouping" logic?

Comment: @Attersson `list_1` contains the lengths of the small, to-be-created sublists.

Comment: Please show what you have tried, and we will be happy to help you fix any problems with your attempt.

Comment: I don't think there's any shorthand logic that can be done for this purpose. For your requirement it has to be done programmatically.

Comment: "brackets in a list"- this semantics concerns me, do you understand that these are lists within the list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an approach that uses an [`iter`ator](https://anandology.com/python-practice-book/iterators.html) for a change.

```
list_1 = [1,2,2]
list_2 = [1,2,3,4,5]

it = iter(list_2)
res = []
for take in list_1:
  res.append([next(it) for _ in range(take)])
print(res)  # -> [[1], [2, 3], [4, 5]]
```

Of course, a list-comprehension version of that exists as well<sup>1</sup>:.

```
it = iter(list_2)
res = [[next(it) for _ in range(take)] for take in list_1]
```

---

Finally, as @Chris_Rands notes in the comments below, you can use [`islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) from the extremely useful [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#module-itertools) module. It takes care of the iterator-creating part of the code above and is this thus more compact.

```
import itertools


res = [list(itertools.islice(list_2, take)) for take in list_1]
print(res)  # -> [[1], [2, 3], [4, 5]]
```

==========================================================================

<sup>1</sup> *Just remember to re-create the iterator!*

Comment: @Chris_Rands I must admit that I have never felt comfortable using `islice` because I don't understand it yet.. Feel free to edit the answer to add your version.

Comment: @Chris_Rands Wasn't too hard to understand afterall. Thanks! :)

Comment: Great! Yah conceptually it's very similar to regular (positive) slicing really once you remember the iterator is exhausted of course, anyway I'll clear up my comments above

Answer (score 2):

This is one approach.

```
list_1 = [1,2,2]
list_2 = [1,2,3,4,5]
c = 0
res = []
for i in list_1:
    res.append( list_2[c:c+i] )
    c += i
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
[[1], [2, 3], [4, 5]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pos = 0
result = []
for amount in list_1:
    result.append(list_2[pos:pos+amount])
    pos += amount
result
# => [[1], [2, 3], [4, 5]]
```

The key is to track the position using cumulative sum of the amounts.

Comment: Giving him teh codez? *Really?*

Comment: It was fun, and he didn't say "gimme".

Answer (score 1):

You can use a *list comprehension.* in combination with *enumerate* function.

```
list_1 = [1,2,2]
list_2 = [1,2,3,4,5]
flist = [list_2[sum(list_1[0:i]) : sum(list_1[0:i]) + val] for i, val in enumerate(list_1)]
```

Output

```
[[1], [2, 3], [4, 5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another simple option:

```
import numpy as np
cum = np.cumsum([0] + list_1)
[ list_2[i:j] for i,j in zip(cum, cum[1:]) ]

#output
[[1], [2, 3], [4, 5]]
```

Comment: One line: `np.split(list_2, np.cumsum(list_1)[:-1])`